# Ajax requests clears the session in Rails 3.0.5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, session

I am writing a Rails application. When I was working with session variables, I observed that the session hash got emptied on reload of a page. I debugged it and accidentally found that in the onload() function, I had fired few Ajax requests to properly handle browser back buttons and apparently these Ajax requests were somehow clearing the session. I commented out these Ajax requests and found that the session variables were not cleared.

I just found out that the problem is not specific to calls from onload but in general, any ajax call seem to clear the session. Can someone explain this behaviour?

In my layout file application.html.erb

```
<body onload="setDefaults()">
```

In my public/javascripts/application.js file

```
function setDefaults()
{
if($('page_type').value == 'create')
    {
        new Ajax.Request('/accessions/show_species', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'selected_value='+$('accession_report_type').value});
        new Ajax.Request('/accessions/display_funds', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'customer_type='+$('accession_customer_type').value});
        new Ajax.Request('/accessions/show_specimen', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'identical='+$('species_is_identical').checked+'&count='+$('species_number').value+'&current_count='+$('specimen_info_div').childElements().length});
    }
}
```

Can some one let me know if I am doing something that I am not supposed to do.

Thanks,